# Python Flask WTForms - Creating dynamic radio elements, working inconsistently

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have the following code to generate a list of playback devices returned from the Spotify API:

```
class SpotifyForm(FlaskForm):
    pass

json_response = response.json()
devicelist = json_response['devices']

devices = {}
for i in range(0, len(devicelist)):
    devices[devicelist[i]['id']] = devicelist[i]['name']

for device in devices:
    choices.append((device, devices[device]))

setattr(SpotifyForm, 'device', RadioField("device", choices=choices))
setattr(SpotifyForm, 'submit', SubmitField('Submit'))

form = SpotifyForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    session['spotify_device'] = form.device.data
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The list is generated properly and it works great in my production flask environment. However, once I move to the production server (Gunicorn), I get the following error traceback:

```
Exception on /spotify [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/composerexplorer/composer-explorer/app/routes.py", line 373, in spotify
    session['spotify_device'] = form.device.data
AttributeError: 'SpotifyForm' object has no attribute 'device'
```

For some reason I get this error once or twice, but then if I keep at it, the error goes away and the form submits correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing something like this when declaring your form class:

```
class SpotifyForm(FlaskForm):
    device = SelectField(choices=my_choices)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Also, I think you should be accessing the data through `form.data`